# cordova throwing error in build

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova returning following error on build

```
cordova build
```

Please find the attached log below

```
Total time: 2.77 secs

/home/user/Softwares/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/user/Softwares/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/user/Softwares/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/user/Softwares/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/user/Softwares/phonegap/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
user@user-Inspiron-1525:~/Softwares/phonegap/hello$ vi ~/.profile 
user@user-Inspiron-1525:~/Softwares/phonegap/hello$ which android
/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
user@user-Inspiron-1525:~/Softwares/phonegap/hello$ ls -ltr /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
-rwxrwxrwx 1 144773 5000 3498 Jun 18 08:12 /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

The environmental variables are below

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

i could create a project using cordova. But, while doing cordova build am getting the error.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Please help to resolve the same ..

Comment: Do you have gradle ?

Comment: @MohammedImranN it saw it getting installed .

Comment: add your gradle path to environment variables

Comment: You may have to download more SDK versions. I had this kind of error when i only had the latest SDK version. After downloading from 17 to latest one, it solved my issue. Hope this helps

Comment: In your Android SDK manager screenshot, I see you haven't installed SDK build tools. Try install the latest SDK build tools and run again.